# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Ok') Axios

Tags: typescript, oop

I believe there a missing thing from my point but I try to invoke `HttpStatusCode.Ok` from Axios Enum
The way I implement is

```
import { HttpStatusCode } from 'axios'

console.log(HttpStatusCode.Ok)
```

But I get weird error which is `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Ok')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This <s>is</s> was a bug in the **just** introduced `HttpStatusCodes` enum. The [PR](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4889) adding it (only 16 days ago as of when you posted your question) added the `enum` to `index.d.ts`, but didn't add the runtime aspect of the `enum` to `lib/axios.js` (since `enum`s aren't *just* type information, they have a runtime aspect as well). See [this issue I've filed for it](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5126), for which someone has already done a PR, it's just waiting on approval.

It's fixed in [v1.2.2 and later](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5404).

Comment: I am using axios@1.2.1 and node@16.16.0 and I'm still getting undefined when I import HttpStatusCode, I saw that it got fixed apparently in a PR but I'm still facing the issue. Is it working for you now?

Comment: @BonisTech - It's fixed in [v1.2.2 and later](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5404) (the current version as I write this, released on Dec 29 2022). (I figured that out by following the link in the issue to the PR, and then following the link at the end of the history for the PR.) I've verified the fix. So if you're using v1.2.1, you need to upgrade to the latest.

Comment: Great, I thought it was fixed in axios@1.2.1. Thanks!